# agGrid not working with Webpack and Coffee script

Tags: coffeescript, webpack, ag-grid

So in Webpack I have the following...

```
var files = glob.sync([
    './src/main/coffee/**/*Module.coffee',
    './src/main/coffee/**/*.coffee'
]);
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/typescripts/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './src/main/typescripts/vendor.ts',
        app: files
    },
    ....
}
```

In my Vendor Typescript file I have `import "ag-grid"`. Finally I have `agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1 angular` in a coffee file.

When I try to run my application I get...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: agGrid is not defined

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

Did you require agGrid in your module?

`app = angular.module 'myApp', ['agGrid']`

Comment: Yeah of course, it also works when I just have the dependency included just not when wrapped by Webpack. Please check your answer before making it.